# VSCode can't find JavaFX or testNG packages, but the program works

Tags: java, visual-studio, javafx

As stated in the title, when I run my program it compiles and passes all tests, but there is still a red underline with the import packages. I have reinstalled VSCode and the extension pack for Java. I am running on Kernel: 5.18.0-2-rt11-MANJARO. I have also attached my settings.json file and the source file for my program. Please let me know if you have any suggestions on how to fix this issue.

```
{
 //settings.json
"java.project.referencedLibraries": [
    "lib/**/*.jar",
    "/home/michaelg/Java/javafx-sdk-18.0.2/lib/javafx.base.jar",
    "/home/michaelg/Java/javafx-sdk-18.0.2/lib/javafx.controls.jar",
    "/home/michaelg/Java/javafx-sdk-18.0.2/lib/javafx.fxml.jar",
    "/home/michaelg/Java/javafx-sdk-18.0.2/lib/javafx.graphics.jar",
    "/home/michaelg/Java/javafx-sdk-18.0.2/lib/javafx.media.jar",
    "/home/michaelg/Java/javafx-sdk-18.0.2/lib/javafx.swing.jar",
    "/home/michaelg/Java/javafx-sdk-18.0.2/lib/javafx.web.jar",
    "/home/michaelg/Java/javafx-sdk-18.0.2/lib/javafx-swt.jar",
    "/home/michaelg/Java/jquery-3.5.1.jar",
    "/home/michaelg/Java/slf4j-api-1.7.9.jar",
    "/home/michaelg/Java/slf4j-simple-1.7.9.jar",
    "/home/michaelg/Java/testng-7.7.0-20220518.034525-1.jar",
    "/home/michaelg/Java/jcommander-1.81.jar"
],
"java.home": "/home/michaelg/Java/jdk-18.0.2.1",
"java.debug.settings.vmArgs": "--module-path \"/home/michaelg/Java/javafx-sdk-18.0.2/lib\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml",
"java.test.config": [
{
    "name": "myConfiguration",
    "workingDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}",
}
],
"java.project.outputPath": "bin"
```

```
package edu.realemj.Example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HowdyFX extends Application {
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btOK = new Button("OK");
        Scene scene = new Scene(btOK, 400, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello from JavaFX!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know or use visual studio code, so can't offer specific advice.  But have you followed the official guide: [JavaFX and Visual Studio Code](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/)?  If so, which option from the documented options are you trying to use?  Non-modular from the IDE?  I'd recommend using a build tool (e.g. maven) integrated with the IDE.

Comment: which imports have red underlines, and what's the problem description when you mouseover / look at the problem details?

Comment: I would definitely not use Visual Studio Code for Java or JavaFX... IntelliJ or Netbeans is way better.